# Feel like doing something

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I've found out that there is a phrase

> feel like verb-*ing*

and that is used to describe a wish for or inclination to something, like

> I feel like drinking tea

But I've also heard this example:

> If I have short vacation, by the time I feel like relaxing, I have to go back home.

It seems that in this case this phrase is suppose to mean

> I begin to relax

Am I correct or I misunderstand?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the meaning is the same in both cases: by the time I wish to *verb* or  by the time I am capable of *verbing*...  However, your example sounds a little strange and artificial to me; I can't quite imagine a native speaker saying that.  Do you have a source for the example?  I would find it easier to imagine a speaker saying "by the time I feel like I can relax" or "by the time I'm starting to relax".

Comment: This was actually in one video about TOEFL speaking section; the samples responses were recorded and this phase was in one of those responses. I would like to believe that native speakers were recorded for that video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases you have to *sense* the meaning of phrases rather than just understand the dictionary definition of the word.

> by the time I feel like relaxing

is another way to say

> by the time I feel like I **am able to relax**.

This is slightly different from

> by the time I feel like I **am relaxed**.

This structure can be used elsewhere with similar meaning:

> I have to have a few drinks before I **feel like singing karaoke**.
>
> Many people don't **feel like learning a sport** until they buy a bunch of expensive equipment for that sport.